# Populate_Extension: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object:

Tags: trigger, opportunity-lineitem

Can anyone help me out with this Error

```
Apex trigger Populate_Extension caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Populate_Extension: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.Populate_Extension: line 23, column 1
```

The Error Line is :

```
ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name;
```

Im writting a trigger on opportunitylineitem .Based on condition as :

Condition 1:

If Product_Line__c == 'DIE'

a)UnitPrice=0.01

b)Newextension__c=Quantity*0.01

c)PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=Bin_Item_Code__c

Condition 2:

If Product_Line__c != 'DIE'

a)UnitPrice=1

b)Newextension__c=Quantity*1

c)PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=PricebookEntry.Product2.Name(It should be the same product name)

Code :

```
trigger Populate_Extension on OpportunityLineItem (Before Insert,Before Update,After Insert,After Update) {
  //List<OpportunityLineItem> ListOpportunityLineItem = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem ol:Trigger.new){
     List<Opportunity> opp= [SELECT Non_Pick_Total__c,Pick_Total__c,Subtotal__c
                                  FROM Opportunity
                                 Where id=:ol.opportunityid];

     if(ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c == 'DIE')
     {
       ol.UnitPrice=0.01;

       ol.Newextension__c=ol.Quantity*0.01;

       ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=ol.Bin_Item_Code__c;

      }
     else if(ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c != 'DIE')
     {
      ol.UnitPrice=1;

      ol.Newextension__c=ol.Quantity*1;

    ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name;
}
}
}
```

The trigger is correct or any blunt mistake .Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: As you are in trigger instance you can directly get the respective object values but not the referred values. So you need a query to get the name from the products... Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name From OpportunityLineItem... Also you need to make use of collections to perform the logic and not supposed to put a query inside the for loop....

Answer (score 1):

The error means that a variable on line 23 is null. There are only 3 things that can be null on the line below.

```
ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name;
```

The three things that could be null and cause this error are:

1. `ol`
2. `ol.PricebookEntry`
3. `ol.PricebookEntry.Product2`

As `ol` is coming from `Trigger.new` then it isn't null. Relationship objects are not populated in triggers so `ol.PricebookEntry` will be null and cause a NullPointerException when you call `ol.PricebookEntry.Product2`.

If you need to reference other objects in a trigger then you will need to query them.